# cuda-memcheck: Could not start the application (14)

Tags: debugging, cuda

I'm trying to use cuda-memcheck to debug my application. Ubuntu 12.04, GeForce GTX 680 / K20c, CUDA 6.5.

Trivial example, `trivial.cu`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void foo()
{
}

int main()
{
  foo<<<1,1>>>();
  printf("CUDA error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));  
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it via `nvcc trivial.cu -o trivial.bin`. Running `./trivial.bin` directly works fine now. It prints the output:

```
CUDA error: no error
```

Now I'm calling it via `cuda-memcheck ./trivial.bin`. `COMPUTE_PROFILE`, `CUDA_PROFILE`, `CUDA_INJECTION32_DLL` and `CUDA_INJECTION64_DLL` are all unset. I have write access to `/tmp`. `$TMPDIR = /var/tmp/625352.1.16C-32G-GPU-K20`, and I can also write to `$TMPDIR`.

I'm getting this output:

```
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Could not start the application (14)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
```

(It might be [SGE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine) related. I'm getting this error only in a non-interactive SGE job.)

I can now reproduce the error in an interactive shell via:

```
mkdir /var/tmp/625352.1.16C-32G-GPU-K20
export TMPDIR=/var/tmp/625352.1.16C-32G-GPU-K20
cuda-memcheck ./trivial.bin
```

So it somehow gets confused with this `$TMPDIR`. This seems like an internal bug in cuda-memcheck.
It seems to happen if the length of `$TMPDIR` is greater or equal than 30 chars.

I have not found a single result on Google about this error, nor in the documentation.

What is the problem? How can I fix the problem? How can I find out what the error means? What does the error code (14) mean? (And where could I ask?)

---

strace output:

```
+ strace cuda-memcheck ./trivial.bin
execve("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin/cuda-memcheck", ["cuda-memcheck", "./trivial.bin"], [/* 122 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1af8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d6f1000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/tls", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/tls", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/atlas-base/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/atlas-base/tls", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/atlas-base/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/atlas-base", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/tls/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/tls", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/x86_64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/x86_64", 0x7fff1cb31520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=115443, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 115443, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430d720000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14768, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430d920000
mprotect(0x2b430d922000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430db22000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x2b430db22000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=135366, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d6f3000
mmap(NULL, 2212904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430db28000
mprotect(0x2b430db40000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430dd3f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x2b430dd3f000
mmap(0x2b430dd41000, 13352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430dd41000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31752, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128984, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430dd48000
mprotect(0x2b430dd4f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430df4e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x2b430df4e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\241\5\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=962656, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3142544, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430df50000
mprotect(0x2b430e032000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430e231000, 40960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe1000) = 0x2b430e231000
mmap(0x2b430e23b000, 82832, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430e23b000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0pU\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1030512, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3125544, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430e250000
mprotect(0x2b430e34b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430e54a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xfa000) = 0x2b430e54a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320(\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88384, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d6f4000
mmap(NULL, 2184216, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430e550000
mprotect(0x2b430e565000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430e764000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14000) = 0x2b430e764000
close(3)                                = 0
open("tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.0/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/atlas-base/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/cuda-6.5/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\200\30\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1815224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3929304, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x2b430e768000
mprotect(0x2b430e91d000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x2b430eb1d000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b5000) = 0x2b430eb1d000
mmap(0x2b430eb23000, 17624, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430eb23000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d6f5000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d6f6000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2b430d6f6340) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430eb1d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430e764000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430e54a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d71a000
mprotect(0x2b430e231000, 32768, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430dd3f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430df4e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430db22000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x2b430d91a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2b430d720000, 115443)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x2b430d6f6610)         = 2023
set_robust_list(0x2b430d6f6620, 0x18)   = 0
futex(0x7fff1cb31e1c, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 1, NULL, 2b430d6f6340) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x2b430db2e750, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2b430db37cb0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x2b430db2e7e0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x2b430db37cb0}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=RLIM_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
futex(0x2b430e23bed0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1af8000
brk(0x1b19000)                          = 0x1b19000
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=28120, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2b430d71b000
statfs("/dev/shm/", {f_type=0x1021994, f_bsize=4096, f_blocks=4116014, f_bfree=4116014, f_bavail=4116014, f_files=4116014, f_ffree=4116011, f_fsid={0, 0}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=4096}) = 0
futex(0x2b430df4f360, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/dev/shm/2023", O_RDWR|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/shm/2023", O_RDWR|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/dev/shm/2023", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC, 0600) = 3
ftruncate(3, 262176)                    = 0
mmap(NULL, 262176, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x2b430d820000
open("/dev/shm/2023", O_RDWR|O_NOFOLLOW|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 262176
mmap(NULL, 262176, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0x2b430d868000
write(1, "========= CUDA-MEMCHECK\n========"..., 112========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= Could not start the application (14)
========= No CUDA-MEMCHECK results found
) = 112
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Comment: are you running any of the profilers or do you have any of [these environment variables](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#known-issues) set?   Can you run your application normally (i.e. `./myprog myargs`) ?

Comment: Is myprog actually a binary executable, or is it a script with a hashbang line (ie. a python program)?

Comment: Using the same OS, GPU and CUDA version I cannot reproduce this problem using your example. It works fine. Are you sure that you have write access to the /tmp filesystem and or the directory from which you are running the program? What do you see if you run through strace?

Comment: @Albert: Seriously? Did it not occur to you that mentioning that this behaviour only happens when running under Sun Grid Engine *might* be pertinent? I am beginning to think the level of disingenuity in your questions isn't accidental.

Comment: @talonmies: I'm seriosly not sure how that can be in any way related. Also, I just figured out this a few minutes before when I added that detail. Please tell me what's different in that situation so I can debug that.

Comment: There are always countless of different things which are different on your machine than on mine. Like the IP adress. The amount of available disk space and memory. The CPU. Etc. It's impossible to post just everything. If you could give me a hint about what could be helpful, I will try to give as much useful information as possible. I have really no idea what to interpret out of this error, so I have no idea what could be related and what is not. If I would only knew what the error means...

Comment: When you launch an non-interactive job in SGE, it is launched by the local exec daemon in a *non-interactive* shell, with the tty piped via a network socket or NFS. That is very, very different to running a command in an interactive shell. Your question is probably "why doesn't cuda-memcheck work under non-interactive shells?" but who could possibly have known that based on what you originally posted? And I don't buy the "i just found it is SGE related" line - you were obviously using SGE non interactive jobs and later found it works as expected in interactive jobs. Details matter....

Comment: As to what is happening, are you really sure that you have paths set correctly so that the executable can be found. There isn't anything obviously wrong in that strace output. The libraries seemed to be found and there is no obvious permission errors.

Comment: The error code printed here is an internal error. It usually corresponds to incorrectly set permissions. Could you check if /tmp is writeable ? Also, is $TMPDIR is set in the SGE non-interactive environment ? If so, is the directory that it points to writable ?

Comment: @talonmies: I already tried whether the tty (i.e. interactive job) matters - it does not. I have still no idea about the difference which is introduces in the SGE job which makes it non-working. If you have any idea, please point that out. I really would like to get that working. The executable can be found.

Comment: @Vyas: It is. But I think that was the problem. Try it yourself, `mkdir /var/tmp/625352.1.16C-32G-GPU-K20`, `export TMPDIR=/var/tmp/625352.1.16C-32G-GPU-K20` -- that does not work for me.

Comment: Btw., @downvoters: You really should think about why you are downvoting on SO. Thanks for trying to make SO a worse place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an internal bug in cuda-memcheck. It seems to happen if the length of `$TMPDIR` is greater or equal than 30 chars. I guess their internal buffer for storing the temp filename is too short.

As a workaround, I now do:

```
ln -s $TMPDIR /tmp/cuda-$PPID
export TMPDIR=/tmp/cuda-$PPID
```

Comment: If you are a registered user, can you try using CUDA 7.0 RC ? Cuda-memcheck in CUDA 7.0 should no longer hit this issue.